# Quantum algorithm to determine the existence of a solution

Tags: grovers-algorithm, oracles

Consider two vectors $u$, $t$ living in some space (let's say $ℝ^{n}$), and the following (simple) problem:

> Find a vector $v$ such that $∃a,b\inℝ$, $au+bv=t$

Imagine I want to use Grover to find a solution vector $v$.

- What oracle could I use to mark only states representing a $v$ allowing the existence of such $(a,b)$ values (that I don't need to know) ?
- More generally is there a way, for some arbitrary equations that can be easily implemented on a quantum computer, to fastly answer the question "is there a solution to this equation ?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a solution to this equation" is the same as asking "Is there a valid assignment of x such that f(x)=1 where f is a boolean function and x is a vector that represents the assignments for the variables in f".

The above is the classical SAT Problem for classical computing. As far as I know, there is no current *efficient* way to solve SAT using quantum computing (Grover's algorithm is still exponential).

Therefore, I believe the answer to your question is no. (not yet at least)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that from here one goes down the rabbit hole of [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) very fast. My answer would be no.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).